# Django auth failure

Tags: django, authentication

I'm really missing what is going on here. Django 1.3.

Symptom: the Authentication is simply busted. I've reduced the problem to this:

```
./manage.py shell
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> users = User.objects.all()
>>> users
[<User: jal>]
>>> users[0].set_password('whatever');
>>> users[0].save()
>>> user = auth.authenticate(username="jal", password="whatever")
>>> print user
None
```

I'm at a loss on this.

Edit:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.get(username="jal")
>>> print user
jal
>>> user.check_password('whatever')
False
```

I'm using the django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend .

Edit two:

```
>>> print user
jal
>>> print user.is_active
True
```

Edit three:

Alasdair is right - thank you.

```
>>> users = User.objects.all()
>>> user = users[0]
>>> user.set_password('whatever')
>>> user.save()
>>> u2 = auth.authenticate(username="jal",  password="whatever")
>>> print u2
jal
```

This still leaves the mystery as to why it is broken for actually accessing the Django admin GUI, which is why I was headed down this road in the first place. It gives me "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive" whether or not the password is correct.

Comment: Now that you've managed to set the password and save it correctly, does the Django admin login work with your new password?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Is there a straightforward way to make Django dump stack traces to a log, or something?

Comment: Correction - I'm running 1.3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having this problem because [Django querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). Each time you access `users[0]`, Django returns a different object.

To demonstrate this, try the following:

```
>>> users = User.objects.all()
>>> print id(users[0])
58753692
>>> print id(users[0])
58753111
```

You can see that the object id is different each time. The object that you save is not the same object that you set the password for. The new password has not been saved to the database, so the authentication fails.

To get around this, you can use assign users[0] to a variable, or user `list()` to force the queryset to be evaluated.

```
# Assign users[0] to a variable.    
users = User.objects.all()
user = users[0]
user.set_password('whatever')
user.save()


# Force the queryset to be evaluated by using list()
users = list(User.objects.all())
users[0].set_password('whatever')
users[0].save()
```

**Edit**: This suggestion was not the problem here, but might help somebody else out.

what is the value of [`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#authentication-backends) in your settings file. You don't have to define it in your `settings.py`, as it will default to:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', )
```

If you have set it to something else, that could cause problems.

Comment: Oops, sorry, formatting issue. the 'users' response is [<User: jal>]. Yes, the user with password 'whatever' is 'jal'. I made it fresh, and it is the only user in this DB.

Comment: Ah, I've fixed the formatting now. You don't need the `pre` block -- just indent 4 spaces for code blocks.

Comment: In response to two, AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
) Also, thanks for the formatting tip.

Comment: >>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.get(username="jal")
>>> print user
jal
>>> user.check_password('whatever')
False

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that the use is active ? (User.is_active)

An inactive user has no permission and can't login (unless you customize things)